# WixEdit - Custom UI sequence

Tags: installation, wix

I am using [WixEdit](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/) to create an installation for our application. I am looking at creating a custom dialog to put in the UI sequence that allows the installer to enter some configuration that goes in the `.config` file that is installed alongside the executable.

However, I am having a little trouble defining the UI sequence. I have created a simple dialog with a text and edit field. I want to display this before the `ProgressDlg`.

I have the following XML in the WXS file:

```
<UI>
    <Dialog Id="ProductConfigurationDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup">
        <Control Type="Text" Id="TextServerName" Width="60" Height="17" X="8" Y="15" Text="OPC Server:" />
        <Control Type="Edit" Id="EditServerName" Width="151" Height="15" X="79" Y="15" Text="[SERVERNAME]" />
    </Dialog>
    <InstallUISequence>
        <Show Dialog="FatalError" OnExit="error" />
        <Show Dialog="UserExit" OnExit="cancel" />
        <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success" />
        <Show Dialog="PrepareDlg" After="LaunchConditions" />
        <Show Dialog="WelcomeDlg" After="MigrateFeatureStates"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></Show>
        <Show Dialog="ResumeDlg" After="WelcomeDlg"><![CDATA[Installed AND (RESUME OR Preselected)]]></Show>
        <Show Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" After="ResumeDlg"><![CDATA[Installed AND NOT RESUME AND NOT Preselected]]></Show>
        <Show Dialog="ProductConfigurationDialog" After="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" />
        <Show Dialog="ProgressDlg" After="ProductConfigurationDialog" />
    </InstallUISequence>
</UI>
```

So my custom dialog is called ProductConfigurationDialog. I have copied the InstallUISequence from UISample.wxs, but I get the following errors.

```
C:\delivery\Dev\wix30_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\FatalError.wxs(29) : error LGHT0170 : The InstallUISequence table contains an action 'FatalError' that is declared in two different locations.  Please remove one of the actions or set the Overridable='yes' attribute on one of their elements.
D:\Sandbox\OPS Wix Install\SetupOPC\SetupOPC\QuorumOPCSetup.wxs(122) : error LGHT0171 : The location of the action related to previous error.
C:\delivery\Dev\wix30_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\UserExit.wxs(29) : error LGHT0170 : The InstallUISequence table contains an action 'UserExit' that is declared in two different locations.  Please remove one of the actions or set the Overridable='yes' attribute on one of their elements.
D:\Sandbox\OPS Wix Install\SetupOPC\SetupOPC\QuorumOPCSetup.wxs(123) : error LGHT0171 : The location of the action related to previous error.
C:\delivery\Dev\wix30_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ExitDialog.wxs(33) : error LGHT0170 : The InstallUISequence table contains an action 'ExitDialog' that is declared in two different locations.  Please remove one of the actions or set the Overridable='yes' attribute on one of their elements.
D:\Sandbox\OPS Wix Install\SetupOPC\SetupOPC\QuorumOPCSetup.wxs(124) : error LGHT0171 : The location of the action related to previous error.
C:\delivery\Dev\wix30_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\PrepareDlg.wxs(35) : error LGHT0170 : The InstallUISequence table contains an action 'PrepareDlg' that is declared in two different locations.  Please remove one of the actions or set the Overridable='yes' attribute on one of their elements.
D:\Sandbox\OPS Wix Install\SetupOPC\SetupOPC\QuorumOPCSetup.wxs(125) : error LGHT0171 : The location of the action related to previous error.
C:\delivery\Dev\wix30_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\WelcomeDlg.wxs(29) : error LGHT0170 : The InstallUISequence table contains an action 'WelcomeDlg' that is declared in two different locations.  Please remove one of the actions or set the Overridable='yes' attribute on one of their elements.
D:\Sandbox\OPS Wix Install\SetupOPC\SetupOPC\QuorumOPCSetup.wxs(126) : error LGHT0171 : The location of the action related to previous error.
C:\delivery\Dev\wix30_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ProgressDlg.wxs(60) : error LGHT0170 : The InstallUISequence table contains an action 'ProgressDlg' that is declared in two different locations.  Please remove one of the actions or set the Overridable='yes' attribute on one of their elements.
D:\Sandbox\OPS Wix Install\SetupOPC\SetupOPC\QuorumOPCSetup.wxs(130) : error LGHT0171 : The location of the action related to previous error.
C:\delivery\Dev\wix30_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ResumeDlg.wxs(46) : error LGHT0170 : The InstallUISequence table contains an action 'ResumeDlg' that is declared in two different locations.  Please remove one of the actions or set the Overridable='yes' attribute on one of their elements.
D:\Sandbox\OPS Wix Install\SetupOPC\SetupOPC\QuorumOPCSetup.wxs(127) : error LGHT0171 : The location of the action related to previous error.
C:\delivery\Dev\wix30_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\MaintenanceWelcomeDlg.wxs(31) : error LGHT0170 : The InstallUISequence table contains an action 'MaintenanceWelcomeDlg' that is declared in two different locations.  Please remove one of the actions or set the Overridable='yes' attribute on one of their elements.
D:\Sandbox\OPS Wix Install\SetupOPC\SetupOPC\QuorumOPCSetup.wxs(128) : error LGHT0171 : The location of the action related to previous error.
```

How can I include an additional custom dialog in my UI sequence?

I am just getting started with WiX so any information or solutions would be most welcome. I am using the latest version of WiX 3.6 with WixEdit 0.7.5.0 to do this.

Comment: Just found the following guide: http://geekswithblogs.net/JanS/archive/2008/12/09/making-a-custom-setup-dialog-using-wix-3.0.aspx

Comment: These links will be helpful: - [Wix Tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain) - [Adding a Custom dialog in WixEdit](http://www.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/archive/2009/11/04/adding-a-custom-dialog-to-your-wix-installer)